# Add 2 Homescreen not working in Firefox - Angular

Tags: angular, firefox, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I made my Angular-Webapp ready for Add 2 Homescreen via
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

Now its perfectly working on Chrome, but not in Firefox.
I am registering on the callback 'beforeinstallprompt' but it's just not firing.
In Chrome I got a 100% score on PWA-Audit.

I also dont see that Firefox would require anything more than Chrome:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Progressive/Add_to_home_screen#How_do_you_make_an_app_A2HS-ready

What am I missing?
You can also check out the page: https://beta.donite.de

Comment: Are you seeing this behavior on the PC or on mobile?

Comment: Firefox is not working mobile nor desktop.Chrome is working on both

Comment: Newest browser versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support it yet check the compatibility table
@ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent , 
However they keep same code block from chrome to may be support in future check below:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Progressive/Add_to_home_screen#How_do_you_make_an_app_A2HS-ready

But as of writing this answer it doesn't support it.